# Suggestions dropdown in reactJS and material UI not working using zIndex

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, z-index

I am trying to make a dropdown menu having the names of cities returned from google maps such that it appears on the top of a division below it using z-Index. Here is the minimal code.

```
class PlacesAutocomplete1 extends React.Component {
  ....

  render() {
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const searchOptions = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: { country: 'in' }
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <PlacesAutocomplete
          value={this.state.address}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSelect={this.handleSelect}
          searchOptions={searchOptions}
          shouldFetchSuggestions={this.state.address.length > 3}
        >
          {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
            <div style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: 2 }}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-search"
                type="search"
                label="city"
                margin="dense"
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                variant="outlined"
                {...getInputProps()}
              />
              <div>
                {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                  const className = suggestion.active
                    ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                    : 'suggestion-item';
                  // inline style for demonstration purpose
                  const style = suggestion.active
                    ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer', position: 'relative', zIndex: 2 }
                    : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer', position: 'relative', zIndex: 2 };
                  return (
                    <Paper {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                      className,
                      style
                    })} elevation={1}>
                      <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                    </Paper>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </PlacesAutocomplete>
        <div style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: 1 }}>
          <h2>Suggestions Should be on the top of Me</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help guide me with what am I doing wrong? Here is the code sandbox demo

[image: Edit optimistic-wood-3vgiw]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but you use relative position and it does not overflow with the next block. You should use `position: absolute` for block with suggestions.
Take look at the forked example here https://codesandbox.io/embed/flamboyant-tree-hc1v6

Comment: Can you explain it in little detail, please?

Comment: To show some block over the other block you should use position absolute or fixed, in that case - your block will not occupy space in page but float over the other elements. You can also move elements with css translate, but in that case, elements will also occupy space which is not good for design.

Combination of position: relative; for parent element and position: absolute: for child allows you to position child element relative to the parent.